# Power query, increment column value based on change in value in another column

Tags: powerquery

In power query I would use the Excel formula as shown in the screen shot link below.

Is there an easy way to do this in Power Query M Code? It doesn't seem so!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you want to add an index by group on Type

Right click Type column, and Group

Use new column name:data, Operation:All Rows and hit ok

Add column .. index column ..  custom and put in your starting numbers and increment

Use arrows atop the data column to expand to new rows

Remove the extra column

sample code:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
#"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Type"}, {{"data", each _, type table}}),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Index", 23, 1),
#"Expanded data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Index", "data", {"Type"}, {"Type.1"}),
#"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded data",{"Type.1"})
in  #"Removed Columns"
```

another way to do it that requires editing code

Right-click the Type column and remove duplicates  (or group, whichever is easier)
Add index
Merge that result back into original data and expand

sample code

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
// remove dupes and create index
#"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(Source),
#"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Removed Duplicates", "Index", 23, 1),
//merge the numbered table back into original
#"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(Source,{"Type"},#"Added Index",{"Type"},"TT",JoinKind.LeftOuter),
#"Expanded Table1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "TT", {"Index"}, {"Index"})
in #"Expanded Table1"
```